# dynamically included pages, sending variable automatically to the url

Tags: php, mysql

I'm studying Php at the moment and that means im very green at it. I have dynamically included my pages and i have a variable defined on my index file and a function page which selects from the db.  The issue is it keeps telling me that the user is not defined, plus I have to add'?bruger_id=1' to the '`http://localhost/bruger/index.php`', to be able to view it like it should. My que is, how can I do this automatically, so I do have to do this.

$bruger_id = $_GET['bruger_id'];

```
$side = 'content';
if(isset($_GET['side'])){
$side = $_GET['side']; /* gets the variable $side */
         }
include("pages/".$side. ".php"); 
/* otherwise, include the default page */
```

*function*
    function bruger_funktioner($bruger_id){

```
    $data=array();
    $results = mysql_query ("SELECT bruger.fk_rolle_id, funktioner.funktion_navn 
                                    FROM bruger
                                        INNER JOIN roller 
                                            ON bruger.fk_rolle_id = roller.rolle_id
                                        INNER JOIN roller_funktioner
                                            ON roller.rolle_id = roller_funktioner.fk_role_id
                                        INNER JOIN funktioner
                                            ON funktioner.funktion_id= roller_funktioner.fk_funktion_id
                                    WHERE bruger.bruger_id = $bruger_id") or die (mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($results)){
        $data  [] = $row['funktion_navn'];
    }   
    return $data;
}
```

menu

Home

Vælg bruger

Answer (score 0):

From what I see is that you are looking for a construct like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['bruger_id'])) {
        //Do the bruger_functioner
    } else { 
        //Maybe do the bruger_functioner with a default id?
    }
 ?>
```

If this is not what you are after, let me know. And explain the question better.

Comment: Hi Tuim, thank you for your ans. though I'm not sure I understand it. if you could pls try explaining it some more

Comment: Well I didn't fully understand your question to begin with. But from what I can see you do not check if ?bruger_id=1 is actually there. But use it anyway. It might help if you give the exact error you get.

Comment: @ Tuim, I have tried writing as you suggested but im still getting the same error. pls help. My que was, how can I make it possible for the page to load automatically with the ?bruger_id on the url, without me having to type it. My code looks as follows:<?php 
             $side = 'content';
       if(isset($_GET['side'])){
        $side = $_GET['side']; /* gets the variable $side */
       }
    include("pages/".$side.".php"); 
     /* otherwise, include the default page */
       ?>

Comment: @CAROLmaina you can use something like `<a href=index.php?brugerid=1>Link</a>`